How to detect success or failure on Stripe payment?
I'm collecting payment information from my users and then charging it periodically.
var paymentIntentCreateOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    Customer = customerId,
    PaymentMethod = paymentMethodId,
    Amount = 123400,
    Currency = "usd",
    OffSession = true,
    Confirm = true,
};
var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
PaymentIntent paymentIntent = paymentIntentService.Create(paymentIntentCreateOptions);

The documentation states:

When a payment attempt fails, the request also fails with a 402 HTTP status code and the status of the PaymentIntent is requires_payment_method.

But what does the code do? Does it throw an exception? Does it return null? And how can I access the reason for the failure?
I'm confused why this very important element of running a transaction is not laid out clearly.

Have you tried looking at paymentIntent.status?

@Barmar: Well, if it threw an exception then I couldn't do that. The problem is how do I test this? I don't know any way to add a bad credit card using Stripe, and in test mode, I don't think there's any amount that will fail.

Stripe has test cards that generate errors specifically for this. See https://docs.stripe.com/testing#declined-payments

If it throws exceptions I'd expect the documentation to say so. Stripe documentation is pretty good about stuff like that.

@Barmar: Unfortunately, the setup form gives me an error if I use one of those bad card numbers. The documentation is pretty thorough, but telling me the HTTP error when I'm using the .NET library does seem to be a bit lacking. I have no idea how to test this.

Are you reading the documentation of the C# SDK or the REST API? I'm not sure why the SDK would refer to HTTP codes.

@Barmar: I'm not sure either. The text I quoted was from this page. The examples are C# for me.

Handling errors documentation. It shows that exceptions are raised, and gives example handler code.

Unfortunately, the setup form gives me an error if I use one of those bad card numbers. Which of those numbers specifically have you tried?

@mjwills i figured I'd use the insufficient funds ones, since I thought maybe that would be detected during the actual transaction.

@Barmar: I tried charging a payment with an invalid payment method ID, and an exception was thrown. So I guess the answer to does it return an error code or throw an exception is that it can do either, according to some rules that Stripe hasn't really laid out. I think that's unfortunate. The error handling should've been made super straight forward.

@JonathanWood that it can do either, What makes you say it can be either? If every example you have tested has thrown an exception? https://docs.stripe.com/error-handling explicitly states: With this library, you don’t need to check for non-200 HTTP responses. The library translates them to exceptions.

@mjwills: Because a PaymentIntent has a Status property, and it's documented as having values that describe failed conditions. However, none of them seem to cover declined payments, so I'm left to guess that those cases cause an exception to be thrown.

It turns out, an error processing a payment can do one of two things.

It can set PaymentIntent.Status to a value other than successful. Other potential values can include requires_payment_method, requires_confirmation, requires_action, processing, requires_capture, or canceled.

It can throw a StripeException. Exceptions are thrown for such conditions as a declined payment method.


Personally, I'd have preferred that all errors are handled in a consistent way. Now my code simply converts any status other than successful to an exception.
